# I am trying to us Xpath in CHrom Driver in Selenium version 4. The xpath is not recognized as an object

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, driver

This is the error I continue to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua8wE.png)

This is the code I continued to use to get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WSe7.png)

I have already downloaded seleniumbase and I believe everything needed to use the Chrome Driver for selenium

Answer (score 0):

`.find_element_by_xpath` and the other variants, `.find_element_by_*` have been deprecated. Instead use

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
```

See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so fast--I see I have to request By from selenium to do this. I will attempt and get back to you

Comment: Sure. I've added the import to the code sample. It's also shown in the documentation that I've linked.

Comment: I tried the code and is not giving me the error anymore because I imported "By"--but the code is still not working

    container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"geo-search-results-collections")]')
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: I'm glad I was able to provide a solution to your question. If you are getting a new error, you will need to take some time to google a solution and if you are unable to find an existing answer, then create a new question.

Comment: If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the question isn't left unanswered.